# android Picasso load image from storage

Tags: android, picasso

i am using Picasso for load image from web and local storage

for load image from web

> Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);

and for load image from storage i add `file://` before path for load image

> Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);

but when file path have utf-8 charchter with file name its not load the image like `file:///android_asset/۲۰۱٧.png`

any idea how to solve it every time i want to use picaso its must string path not `Uri` or `File` because its saved in sqlite as string

Comment: I tried putting an image with that file name in my assets folder and Picasso loads it into an ImageView without any problem.  I used Picasso 2.5.2, if that matters.

Comment: To clarify, Picasso v2.5.2 works correctly for me when I use the path "file:///android_asset/۲۰۱٧.png" as is, without any encoding (as answers below are suggesting).   Perhaps something else is causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/۲۰۱٧.png";
URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
URIUtil.encodeQuery(url)
```

see the issue at:

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/652